# Roots of trigonometric polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, polynomials

let $a=(a_0,a_1,...,a_n)$ and $P_a(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k \cos (kx) $
define $b=(a_n,a_{n-1},...,a_0)$
If $Z_a$ is the number of roots of $P_a$ on $[0,2\pi[$

then $$Z_a+Z_b \geq 2n$$

I have failed to find a clever algebra trick, I've tried multiplying $P_a$ and $P_b$ and tried induction on $deg (P)$ but to no avail.

Comment: Is it greater or requal than $n$ or $2n$ ?

Comment: it says it is supposed to be $\geq 2n$

Comment: Are $a_i$s and $b_i$s real or complex?

Comment: they are real mustapha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using complex analysis. I'll suppose first that $a_0 \neq 0$ and $a_n \neq 0$. Let $Q_a(z) = a_0 + a_1 z + ... + a_nz^n$, and similarly for $Q_b$. Let $C$ denote the unit circle in the plane. Now, if $Q_a$ has $m$ zeroes in the unit disk, then the image $f(C)$ winds $m$ times around 0; see the wiki page on "Argument principle" if you are unfamiliar with this fact. Each times it winds around zero it must strike the imaginary axis at least twice, giving your trig polynomial at least two zeroes. So you get 2 times the number of zeroes of $Q_a$ in the unit disk as a lower bound for $Z_a$. Similarly for $Z_b$ and $Q_b$, however $Q_b(z) = z^n Q_a(1/z)$, which means $Q_b$ has a zero inside the disk whenever $Q_a$ has a zero outside the disk. This gives a lower bound for $Z_b$, and basically $Z_a+Z_b$ is at least two times the number of zeroes of $Q_a$, which is $n$, as long as $Q_a$ has no zeroes on the unit circle $C$. However, if $Q_a(z) = 0$ with $z \in C$ then $Q_b(1/z)=0$ as well, giving you a zero of both $P_a$ and $P_b$, so that zero is essentially counted twice as well, and the result follows.

When $a_0=0$ or $a_n=0$, you can write $Q_a(z) = H_a(z)z^r$ and $Q_b(z) = H_b(z)z^s$ for $H_a$, $H_b$ with nonzero leading coefficients, and some $r$ and $s$. Then just apply the above reasoning to $H_a$, $H_b$, together with the extra zeroes from $z^r$ and $z^s$ gives you what you want.

Hope that helps.
Greg

Comment: In fact , this problem is to be solved in the realm of real analysis only, if I have to resolve to complex analysis ( which i am trying to do at the moment ) , I have to modify the solution so that " doesn't look like I'm using complex analysis". That being said , is it possible to further expand on this solution using real analysis only ?

Comment: Sorry, but I would have no idea how to do this without complex analysis. I don't think this proof can be translated, really. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks anyway , thanks for the insight , i will study this further

Comment: By the way, would you mind telling me where you found this problem?

Comment: I created a second thread, I want a complete proof of this problem maybe you could help then i will tell you where I found this problelm

Comment: I did get it to work, please see the other thread on this topic.